# Logical operators precedence in C

Tags: c, logical-operators, operator-precedence

Do logical operators have precedence in C (like `&&` being executed after `||` or vice-versa) or do they execute from left to right? I usually use parentheses to make sure they execute correctly, but someone asked me about this and I was not sure.

For example is `a || b && c == 2` interpreted as `(((a || b) && c) == 2)` or `(a ||( b && (c == 2)))`

Comment: [cppreference operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5

Comment: What are you even asking? `&&` is logical AND, `||` is logical OR, `==` is the equality operator, **`?:` is the conditional operator**, which is notably absent in your question apart from the tag. Are you asking about the conditional operator, or about random non-related operators in general? Also "... precedence in C or do they execute from left to right" doesn't make any sense. Operator precedence and order of evaluation are two different things.

Comment: Seriously? This question is answered somewhere in the first 10 pages of K&R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is interpreted as `(a ||( b && (c == 2)))`

The `&&` have a higher priority over the `||`, as you can see here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0):

Logical AND has precedence before Logical OR.

The '==' has precedence before logical OR and AND.

Please have a look at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence